# How can I make dashed line cube in blender?

Tags: texturing

I want to make a cube for which the lower border are dashed line like this one : [image: Cube]

Should I make an appropriate texture ? Or is there any another way ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can do this with "Freestyle".

1. turn it on with the checkbox on the view layer properties and add a second lineset

[image]

2. select the "dashed line" checkbox and enter some values:

[image]

3. in edit mode tap on "face select"

[image]

select the top face

[image]

and select "face"-"face data"-"mark freestyle face"

[image]

Result:

Please be aware, i made this result on purpose so you can see how i did it:
I added 2 linestyles so that one "hides" the other.
Of course you have to change the color and thickness of the one linestyle to completely cover the other one.

[image]

Settings of my linesets:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much !

Comment: you are welcome!